# OSError at / [Errno 2] No such file or directory django assets

Tags: django

I'm trying to run command for build static

```
./manage.py assets build --settings=marketplace.settings.dev
```

and I get traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./manage.py", line 10, in <module>
execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 399, in execute_from_command_line
utility.execute()
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 392, in execute
self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 242, in run_from_argv
self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 285, in execute
output = self.handle(*args, **options)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_assets/management/commands/assets.py", line 88, in handle
impl.run_with_argv(args)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/script.py", line 547, in run_with_argv
return self.run_with_ns(ns)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/script.py", line 537, in run_with_ns
return cmd.invoke(ns.command, args)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/script.py", line 371, in invoke
return function(**args)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/script.py", line 171, in __call__
disable_cache=no_cache)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 563, in build
disable_cache=disable_cache))
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 498, in _build
force, disable_cache=disable_cache, extra_filters=extra_filters)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 384, in _merge_and_apply
filters_to_pass_down, disable_cache=disable_cache)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/bundle.py", line 453, in _merge_and_apply
return filtertool.apply(final, selected_filters, 'output')
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 269, in apply
return self._wrap_cache(key, func)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 216, in _wrap_cache
content = func().getvalue()
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/merge.py", line 249, in func
getattr(filter, type)(data, out, **kwargs_final)
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/filter/coffeescript.py", line 45, in output
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Can i get some relevant advice on how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

The error is on your 3rd-party app [django-assets](https://github.com/miracle2k/django-assets), which uses another 3rd-party python app [webassets](https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets), which is intended to compress and minimize web assets like Javascript, CSS, etc.

The problem is on **webassets**, which hides the exception on having a bad configuration, the actual reason is *not finding the binaries needed to perform the compression*. **Here you have the reason of the error**: https://github.com/miracle2k/webassets/issues/400

Make sure you have the OS dependencies needed properly installed (binaries) to allow django-assets+webassets perform the operations you need. I had similar issues when first trying other apps for the same purpose like django-pipeline, having problems if **yuglify** or other compression backends where not properly installed.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see, he couldn't find your marketplace-settings. `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory`

Is your `marketplace.settings.dev` located here:

- `/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` or
- `/usr/lib/python2.7/`?

Try to move the `marketplace` directory and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your manage.py file and make sure this line points to the right settings file

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "marketplace.settings.dev")
```

Answer (score 0):

`File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django_assets/management/commands/assets.py", line 88, in handle`

and further lines indicates that your command actually ran.

So I think there's nothing wrong with `marketplace.settings.dev`

```
File "/home/web/market/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/webassets/filter/coffeescript.py", line 45, in output
stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 709, in __init__
errread, errwrite)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 1326, in _execute_child
raise child_exception
OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Indicates that your `asset` command is excuting a subprocess and one of the files that the subprocess is trying to access doesn't exist.

I guess that a directory you are passing to the subprocess in your `asset` command has problem. (path incorrectly set)

I may be able to further assist you if you show the `asset` command code.